# Rails server not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
`start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

I can confirm that this is a not a port issue. It happened after I changed by /etc/hosts file to use my custom domain name pointing to 127.0.0.1 but after I changed that rails server is not starting in any port.

The command I am using to star: rvmsudo `rails s -p 80`

Here is how my etc/hosts file look like

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       platform.adwyze.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost 
::1             platform.adwyze.com
```

Comment: Do you necessarily need to start in 80 port?

Comment: No I have tried starting in other ports also. It is a privileges issue more likely.

Answer (score 2):

Usually rails server being started by `rails s` or `rails s -p 5000`.
I guess it should not being started in 80 port. 
Try to start it by these commands instead `rails s -p 80`

**UPDATE**:
You can find and kill after process that using 3000 by:

`lsof -i :3000`

`kill -9 found_pid`

Also it's possible to run the server by `bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001`

Comment: It's not starting in any port after I change the /etc/hosts file

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: I guess it's so because of you've set you  platform.adwyze.com for 127.0.0.1

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be. I need to open localhost for that address.

Comment: @ArindamBarman It'd be cool to see you output of `ps aux | grep rails`

Comment: @ArindamBarman does it work for you? `bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001`

Comment: No rails server running

Comment: yes starting by mentioning the ip explicitly. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `sudo rails server -p 80`, and if platform.adwyze.com is on https, change https to http on the chrome address bar, and then platform.adwyze.com will point to your local server.